# Is NAFTA currently in effect, and/or will it be in effect should the United States-Mexico-Canada Agreement (USMCA) fail?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, trade, canada, mexico

I'm curious about the current state of NAFTA.  Was it terminated to make way for the new agreement, or is passing the new agreement the trigger for the removal of NAFTA?

Basically, if the new trade agreement does not pass, is NAFTA still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes NAFTA is and will remain in force until the USMCA is ratified by (all) its members. [Official word](https://ustr.gov/trade-agreements/free-trade-agreements/united-states-mexico-canada-agreement):

> While the United States, Mexico, and Canada have concluded a new, rebalanced agreement, NAFTA currently remains in effect. The USMCA can come into effect following the completion of TPA procedures, including a Congressional vote on an implementing bill.

Now Trump could change his mind again, but insofar he [gave up threatening](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/03/07/trump-nafta-democrats-1247064) to just withdraw from NAFTA if Congress doesn't pass USMCA.

> Aides said there were no immediate plans to withdraw from the 25-year-old agreement, though the president hasn't completely ruled out doing it eventually if the negotiations over approving USMCA fall apart.